Commands within headings or sections
Is there any way to put a command inside a section? Like in the case below:
\section{About \minisec}


This is exactly what this section will explain about this command.
I am translating some parts of the KOMMA-Script Manual into Portuguese. This section will be part of the TOC, like the others.

It depends... what is \minisec and/or what does it do?

Section titles get copied to several places: the header, the toc, the pdf bookmarks, possibly others.  Some of those copies are more resilient than others.  The way they will break will depend on what the command does; the way they will be fixed will depend on the way they broke.

you probably want something like About \texttt{\textbackslash minisec}

If you want to expand \minisec, you can usualy use \protect\minisec.  There is also the optional "short title" which is used exclusively for the TOC and header.

You can't use \verb in the argument to another command, but you can define a suitable command for the job:
\NewDocumentCommand{\cmd}{m}{\texttt{\symbol{`\\}#1}}

Full example
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\cmd}{m}{\texttt{\symbol{`\\}#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{About \cmd{minisec}}

The command \cmd{minisec} is very useful.

\end{document}


If you use hyperref you need something else.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\cmd}{m}{\texttt{\symbol{`\\}#1}}

\newcommand{\hycmd}[1]{\textbackslash#1}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\cmd\hycmd}

\begin{document}

\section{About \cmd{minisec}}

The command \cmd{minisec} is very useful.

\end{document}

